# Input for a bool value (python)

Tags: python, boolean

I am making a True/False test program in Python. How can I prompt the user for a boolean value, store this value in a variable, and then use it in if or else statement?

Comment: can you show some examples which you have tried

Comment: is it a user input you are trying or its defined??

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: @Vivs  A user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import ast

user_input = ast.literal_eval(input('Enter True or False:'))
print(user_input, type(user_input))
```

If you enter "True" or "False", it will evaluate to `True` or `False` respectively.

If you want to go a step further, consider that the user could enter something very different than True and False, so you can handle it with the following logic:

```py
import ast

try:
    user_input = ast.literal_eval(input('Enter True or False:'))
except Exception:
    print('You did not enter True/False.')
else:
    if not isinstance(user_input, bool):
        print('You did not enter True/False.')
    else:
        if user_input:
            print('You enter True')
        else:
            print('You enter False')
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a normal string input. `bool(input())` won't work.

```
boolean = input('Enter bool: ')
if boolean == 'True':
    pass
elif boolean == 'False':
    pass
```